# return statement inside a "with"

Tags: python, with-statement

My basic understanding of the "with"-idiom is this:

Calling

```
with obj:
  further code.. inside with
#endwith
code after if block
```

means that after the with-block ended, the `__exit__` method on obj will be called.
However, assume I have the with-call within a function definition, and inside it, the code has the following structure:

```
def fct():
  with obj:
     return call_other_fct(params)
```

Now my question: When does the `__exit__` run?

1. After the execution of the return statement
2. Before the execution of the return statement but after the call to `call_other_fct`
3. It does not run at all